# Why are classes called classes in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why “class” for class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118495/why-class-for-class-in-java)

I was thinking about type classes in Haskell, which allow you to separate types into different groups based on the operations you can perform on them.  But why are classes called classes in C++?  What were they originally meant to classify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because they were called "classes" in Simula. Sources indicate that Simula was influenced by [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1061041) proposal for "record classes" (i.e. structured data with associated type information) in Algol. Mostly every other language derived its OO terminology (directly or indirectly) from Simula.

Answer (score 5):

to categorize a real world entity (objects) .

Comment: Not sure about the "real world" part.

Comment: everything around you can be thought as an object of a particular class or you can say entities which have some common property and behavior can be kept in particular class to indicate them by a common group.

Comment: Yes, but mathematician and computer scientists also like to categorize and classify abstract non-real-word things and concepts.

Comment: @Thilo: I understand that is just a nitpick and that you do understand what the answer means. Call them *domain entities* if you wish, rather than *real world entities*, but at any rate it is a taxonomy of objects in the program.

Comment: Nit-picking aside, I do take umbrage at the idea that OOP has much to do with real-world objects. Mentioning them makes this answer worse than Brian's or Greg's.

Answer (score 3):

Classes in C++ are meant to classify *objects*.

Answer (score 3):

They classify objects, hence the name :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually the uncommon use is the one in haskell. In most OO languages *class* is used to refer to a type that defines the behavior of a class of objects. For example, `Car` is a class of objects of which there are many instances, my car, your car, someone elses car. In Haskell, the term is used in a metalanguage level to refer to classes of types, rather than classes of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, you have objects which have state and support some operations. The state and stuff is wildly different for some different objects (e.g. an object representing a bank account in a financial program, vs an object representing a car in a racing simulator). So we can't treat all objects the same way.

A *class* represents a bunch of objects which work similarly. If you know that an object belongs to some class, then you know some kinds of things you can do with it. Objects representing a bank account might support operations like `deposit`, `withdraw`, `getBalance`, `getAccountHolder`.

Talking about "the class of objects which support the `deposit`, `withdraw`, `getBalance`, and `getAccountHolder` operations", or "the class of objects which support the `accelerate`, and `getSpeed`, and `steer` methods" is just normal use of the word "class" (and is related to "classify", which basically just means "to put into classes"; the word "class" as in a group of students is quite different).

Obviously, you pretty quickly want to *name* particular classes, so that you can just say `BankAccount` or `RacingCar`, rather than "the class of objects which support ...".

So a class is just that; a "thing" that defines what is common to the objects which are instances of the class.